# How do I find all integers that satisfy this condition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Suppose that $72x + 56y = 40$. Find all $x,y$ that satisfy this condition.

Here is what I did:

1. I reduced the equation to give $9x + 7y = 5$
2. But since 5 is relatively prime to 7 and 9, we know $x,y$ is divisible by 5. So we can reduce the equation to $9(5a) + 7(5b) = 5$.
3. Simplifying, we get $9a + 7b=  1$. Would it be easier to continue along this direction, i.e. to find some $a,b$ such that their gcd is one? I cannot continue beyond this as I have no other insights left.

What kind of available theorems/techniques can I use to solve this?

Comment: The statement "But since 5 is relatively prime to 7 and 9, we know $x,y$ is divisible by 5." is false.  Take $x=6,y=-7$ for instance.

Comment: $$  28 - 27 = 1 $$  What is $5 \cdot 28 - 5 \cdot 27 \; \; ?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write $$7y\equiv 5\mod 9$$ so $$y\equiv \frac{5}{7}\equiv \frac{14}{7}\equiv 2\mod 9$$
and we find $x$ as
$$9x+7(2+9k)=0$$ so $$x=-1-7k$$

Comment: Thanks for this insight -- I didn't know we could have fractions for modular arithmetic. Will this work for all numbers or must it be that for some (mod m), m is relatively prime to the coefficients?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418693/modular-arithmetic-using-fractions

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is this a particular technique that I can read up more about somewhere?

Comment: we can write every linear Diophantine equation as a Modulo equation

Comment: Checking: should line 3 be $9x + 7(2+9k) = 5$ instead? because $9x + 7y = 5$ and not 0.

Answer (score 0):

$$9x+7y=5$$

First, you find **a** solution.
\begin{array}{rcll}
   5-7(1) &= &-2 \\
   5-7(2) &= &-9 \\
   9(-1) + 7(2) &= &5
\end{array}

Because $\gcd(9,7)=1$, the general solution is

$$(x,y) = (-1+7t, 2-9t)$$

for all $t \in \mathbb Z$.

Now take the general case $9x+7y=5$ and subtract $9(-1)+7(2)=5$.

\begin{array}{cccc}
   9x &+ &7y &= &5 \\
   9(-1) &+ &7(2) &= &5 \\
 \hline
   9(x+1) &+ &7(y-2) &= &0 \\
   &&9(x+1) &= &7(2-y)
\end{array}

Since $9$ and $7$ are relatively prime, then $9$ must divide $2-y$, let's say $ 2-y = 9t$ for some integer, $t$. Hence $y = -9t + 2$ for some integer, $t$. Substituting that back into $9(x+1) = 7(2-y)$, we get $9(x+1)=63t$. We can simplify that to $x = 7t - 1$.

So the most general solution is

$$9(7t-1) + 7(-9t+2) = 5$$